# Apache NetBeans IDE 12.0 "Activation Failed"

Tags: java, java-14, netbeans-12

Try to create a new project (Java with Ant -> Java Application)

However, I get the following errors:

[image]
I've tried many ways and also uninstall and reinstall the jdk14 and Apache Netbeans 12.0 plenty of times but the error still remain the same.

What can I do TT   Is there any solution to solve this error? Much appreciate.

Comment: try this link https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=245628

Comment: regarding posting textual content as image, please check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447 and [ask], then edit your question to fit